# Using SSPI to get SSO from Java application running on Windows

Tags: java, windows, kerberos, jaas

I have a Java application running on Windows that needs to authenticate to a webapp using Kerberos/SPNEGO.  I'm aware of how to configure JAAS to achieve this, but I find the Java (JDK6 and JDK7beta) Kerberos implementation to be lacking a couple important features I need.  For example, support for referrals or using the DNS to figure out the realm of a host (I have a multi-realm environment).

Is there a third-party module that can implement authentication using the Windows native [SSPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380493(VS.85).aspx)?  We've already gone through the trouble of configuring our Windows clients to work within our environment, it'd be nice to not have to do it again for Java.  I'm aware of [Waffle](http://waffle.codeplex.com) and its WindowsLoginModule, but it doesn't seem to do SSO as it requires users to re-enter their credentials into the application.

Comment: Please note that the statement that "I'm aware of Waffle and its WindowsLoginModule, but it doesn't seem to do SSO as it requires users to re-enter their credentials into the application." is incorrect. Waffle does SSO, that's what it was designed for and any prompt is an issue in configuration.

Comment: There is BTW enhancements going into latest OpenJDK to use default credentials of SSPI without the need of external libraries: http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/RFR-6722928-Support-SSPI-as-a-native-GSS-API-provider-td357710.html

Answer (score 3):

We've had a similar issue. The main problem for us was that the GSS-API implementation fails when using Windows UAC and we solved it using Waffle.

[Waffle](https://github.com/dblock/waffle) is basically a wrapper for the JNA calls to SSPI. We've managed to implement SSO using Waffle by overriding the class `sun.net.www.protocol.http.NegotiatorImpl`:

```
package sun.net.www.protocol.http;

import java.io.IOException;
import waffle.windows.auth.impl.WindowsSecurityContextImpl;

public class NegotiatorImpl extends Negotiator {

private String serviceName;

public NegotiatorImpl(HttpCallerInfo hci) throws IOException {
    this.serviceName = "HTTP/" + hci.host.toLowerCase();
}

    @Override
    public byte[] firstToken() throws IOException {
        return WindowsSecurityContextImpl.getCurrent("Negotiate", serviceName).getToken();
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] nextToken(byte[] in) throws IOException {
        return new byte[0];
    }
}
```

Then you can create a JAR with holding only this class and copy it along with the Waffle & JNA JARs to *./jre/lib/endorsed* of your JVM. Using the [Java Endorsed Standards Override Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) of the JVM, this replaces the default `Negotiator` implementation of the JVM.

Comment: I've given this a try but those methods don't seem to be called.  I see jar being loaded from jre/lib/endorsed, but I've added a couple prinln to firstToken and nextToken and I don't see them.  My test code simply does URL.openConnection against a server with SPNEGO.  I can confirm it works with JAAS but it's doing exactly the same once I drop the NegotiatorImpl override into endorsed.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I realized I mixed up the packages. For 1.6 it is `sun.net.www.protocol.http.NegotiatorImpl` and for 1.7 it is `sun.net.www.protocol.http.spnego.NegotiatorImpl`. Can you check whether those exist in your JVM?

Comment: That worked! Now I have the problem that some sites require a functioning nextToken