# Calling a .NET web service from within a Java web app in Tomcat with NTLM / Kerberos

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, tomcat, ntlm

I have a Java webapp that contains an HttpClient to a remote .NET SOAP web service. So far, so good. The Java webapp runs inside Apache Tomcat on a Windows Server and uses a service account.

Unfortunately, that remote .net web service uses NTLM. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36584484/1021725) gives me some insight into how to do it. But it seems that the configuration stills requires a username/password rather than leveraging the service account Tomcat is running with. Also, I'm not sure what the Java authenticator should look like (as seen [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/http-auth.html)).

Has anyone ever attempted this?

### Update

Some interesting links:

- Different [authentication schemes](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient-win/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/win/ClientWinAuth.java) supported in Apache HTTP Components
- Sample for [NTLMv2 authentication](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient-win/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/win/ClientWinAuth.java) - I have yet to test it.

Comment: Are you trying to access the tomcat service account in  java wep app ( don't think this is possible) ? Or Are you trying to figure out how to send NTLM credentials to .net web service ?

Comment: The latter. I want to call a .net ws from within a Java web app inside tomcat on a Windows server. The .net ws expects ntlm authentication and I want to leverage the service account tomcat is running as

Comment: Take a look at Waffle as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580099/using-sspi-to-get-sso-from-java-application-running-on-windows

Comment: Dont leverage the tomcat service accounts. The account is meant to run Tomcat not do WS calls. If this account gets compromised this means you have access to  not just the tomcat server but also access to calling web service and potentially siphon of other information. In short this weakens your security  model.

Comment: What's the alternative though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that on Java 7/8 with Tomcat 8.x, the following is enough to leverage NTLM authentication "transparently".

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
```

Followed by

```
boolean useWindowsAuthentication = true;
HttpUriRequest request;
CloseableHttpClient httpclient;
if (useWindowsAuthentication){
    log.info("Using Windows Authentication");
    httpclient = WinHttpClients.createDefault();    
} else {
    httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
}
```